# выбрать максимальное значение в цикле

Tags: php

У меня есть цикл, который выводит опции товаров с ценой. Как сделать так, чтобы в тэге `radio` всегда была пометка `checked` у опции с максимальной ценой?

```
<?php foreach ($option['product_option_value'] as $option_value) { ?>
<input type="radio" name="option[<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>]" value="<?php echo $option_value['product_option_value_id']; ?>" />
<?php echo $option_value['name']; ?>
<?php echo $option_value['price']; ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Надо в начале сложить максимальное значение в переменную `$max`, а потом просто с ней сравнивать `<input type="radio" name="option[<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>]" value="<?php echo $option_value['product_option_value_id']; ?>" <?= $option_value['price'] == $max ? 'checked': '' ; ?> />`

Comment: спасибо за помощь, работает! :)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Код в комментах читать неудобно, оформляйте ответом.

Comment: @AK ......done!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надо в начале сложить максимальное значение в переменную `$max`, а потом просто с ней сравнивать

```
<input type="radio" ....... <?= $option_value['price'] == $max ? 'checked': '' ; ?> />
```

Каким образом вы найдете максимальное значение - решать вам. Если бы они были у вас все массивом, то достаточно было сделать так:

```
$max = max($array_of_values);
```